# Read filename to the textbox from fileupload window

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

In my asp.net application, I have used `Textbox`, `button` and a `hidden fileupload control`.
When Button is clicked using jquery I am getting the `fileupload window` as below,

```
protected void btn_browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
    strScript.Append("$(document).ready(function(){");
    strScript.Append("$('#FileUpload1').click();");
    strScript.Append("});");
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", strScript.ToString(), true);
    txt_fileName.Text=FileUpload1.FileName;
}
```

My issue is I am unable to show the selected filename from `fileupload` to the `textbox`.
The filename is not displaying in the `textbox`

Any suggessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On serverside you can do like this:**

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fID.PostedFile.FileName);
fID.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files/"+filename));
string fpath = "Files/"+filename;
```

**and with jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
   $("#btnFileUpload").click(function () {  
        var FUpload = $("#FileUploadControl").val();  
    }
 }
```

**For JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getFileName() {
var varfile = document.getElementById("FileUploadControl");
document.getElementById("filename").value = varfile.value;
}
</script>
```

***FileUpload control will be :***

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" onchange="getFileName()"
```